# Cordova: Javascript loads before the html elements are loaded

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've a [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Now I want to initate a datepicker event through javascript. The html element to which I want to apply the datepicker is following and is defined in the `index.html`.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Departure date..." data-provide="datepicker" class="calendar-box">
```

And here's the javascript code defined in the `main.js` file.

```
$('.calendar-box').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

When i debug this code and try to find `$('.calendar-box')` it gives me an empty array which means that the html elements are not defined by the time this piece of code is running.

Here's the order of scripts being loaded.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/assets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/assets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

The quesstion is how can I run the script such that $('.calendar-box') gives me the right tag. I already tried putting the javascript code under the `deviceReady` event and `document.ready`. But still get an emptry array for `calendar-box`.

Let me know if you need to know something else.

Comment: Have you tryed combining both events? `$(document).ready()`, then `deviceready`.

Comment: Put the scripts before the closing body tag?

Comment: yes @Wikiti, it didn't work

Comment: @evolutionxbox they are exactly before the closing body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about blocking, throw the script inside document.write

```
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/assets.js"><' + '\/script>');
```

If you do care, you can use something like requireJS, or something like a poor man's loader, call it Async (not to be confused by anything better)

```
 /**
  * Async accepts a url and a callback, it loads the script, adding an eventListener
  * to make sure the callback is done when the script is loaded
  * @param {String} some url
  * @param {onLoadCallback} you do whatever you want when this callback is called
  **/
  var loadAsyncScript = function(url, onLoadCallback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

   if (onLoadCallback) {
     // assign event before src is set,
     // IE may start getting scripts just after src is assigned and before script is attached to DOM
     attachEvent(script, 'load', onLoadCallback);
   }

   script.async = true;
   script.src = '//' + url;
   parent.parentNode.insertBefore(script, parent);
};
```

Comment: you can use it as 
loadAsync({{someURL}}, function() {
  // put your code here
});

Comment: hey thanks, but I don't get how will this help in solving my problem ?

Comment: well, document.write is blocking, so it will render in it's block and the browser will not do anything until it is done, putting those scripts at the end of your body, it running those scripts in order and when the rest of the page comes to it (in case one of those scripts load something async inside)

Comment: As for the second approach, it runs things async, same concept, async scripts generally run when the DOM is ready and not before. I am going by your answer that says you've used (function(){ /* your code here */})(); because this is what usually guarantees that the script is ran when the DOM is loaded and interactive. If you have done all of the above and still have the problem, I think your issue is a bug elsewhere